# Profiling Vs Archiving - different code signing requirements?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

In XCode5, is it still the case that if you want to profile a release build of your app, then archive it for distribution, you have to manually change the provisioning profiles in build settings? That's how I remember it being in XCode4 - building with a distribution provisioning profile means XCode can't hook the process on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> building with a distribution provisioning profile means XCode can't hook the process on the device.

If you build for distribution through the App Store, the program won't run at all until it has been signed by Apple. So yes, you'd still need to change the provision profile in order to run the app so that you can profile it.

Comment: But there's no less error-prone mechanism, we're still left with hacking schemes and/or build settings when we want to build a version for iTunes, then hacking back to continue development?

Comment: It's just one build setting, no hacking required. But yes, you still have to switch profiles if you want to run the app. I suppose an alternative is to duplicate the tartget and then set up the debug and release settings so that they're identical except for the profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you archive an application it is signed with the provision profile that you have indicated to use under its build configuration.

An archived app can be resigned with a different provision profile at a later time (though the organizer or command line), so in a way, they are independent of provision profile.

Comment: That's interesting. So I can build an archive version of my app with developer profile and copy it to iPad using XCode as normal? Then re-sign and upload the re-signed version to ITunesConnect?